# How to give http (not encrypted) access to a pass for development?

Tags: ios9, xcode7, passkit

Apple's WWDC 2012 video demonstrates how a Passbook pass can talk to a server; with the condition that the communication is restricted to https (SSL). The video demonstrated how developers can enable non-SSL communication using the "developer" menu and select "allow http services" under the PassKit sub-menu.

That is no longer an option.

How can we achieve the same thing now in iOS 9 and XCode 7?

-- UPDATE 12/13/15 --

I can access "Developer -> Settings -> Allow HTTP Services" on the iOS Simulator. Is this all we have or can we have a "Developer" menu on a physical device too? Perhaps this is my confusion. Thanks for any clarification!

-- UPDATE 12/16/15 --

The issue was resolved! Here is my advise for anyone having this issue in the future. On developer.apple.com, Go to "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" and under iOS choose "Devices". You should see a list of approved devices. You'll see "Developer" listed under "Provision Profiles".

Now:

1 - Be sure to select the devices you want to carry over to a renewed membership. When you renew a developer account, you may get a warning about this in your developer profile online.

2 - Make sure the phone is specifically provisioned for development. You do this with your developer account online with Apple.

3 - Between your phone and your workstation, be sure Xcode and iOS are matching release pairs. This is a gotcha if you've updated one of either iOS or Xcode but not the other.

Comment: The option is still there in iOS 9.2.

Comment: @i40west -- Do you do something special to get it? I don't have a "Developer" in settings.

Comment: @i40west -- Okay I understand the confusion I might be creating. I can access "Settings -> Developer" in the *simulator* but not on the physical device. Is it possible to do this on the physical device?

Comment: It is on my phone. Have you ever used the phone with Xcode?

Comment: @i40west -- I've installed a few apps and have a few provisions on there via Cordova. I can see a few iOSTEAM provision profile there. I read somewhere to turn on Xcode, open the Device window, and reboot the phone. I did that, but I don't see that in the phone. Any ideas?

Comment: Not really. If your phone is provisioned for development—if you can install things on it from Xcode—then that menu should be there. Double-check and make sure it is. Try compiling and installing an app from Xcode.

Comment: @i40west Thanks! It helped a lot knowing that this feature was definitely there for people. It turns out that I had three issues.

1 - Resetting phones after renewing developer membership.
2 - As you mentioned, making sure the phone was indeed provision for development purposes
3 - Making sure that iOS and Xcode were set to a matching release pair. Resolved for me by updating both the iPhone and Xcode